# User submitted CSV file upload UTF-8 concern

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a feature that uploads a user submitted CSV file into my database using `fgetcsv` etc.

My database has a collation of utf8_general_ci and the website charset is set to utf-8.

How can I ensure that when inserting the data from CSV into my database for display on the website, the correct encoding is set?

Do I have to test every string using something like `mb_detect_encoding` (seems a bit memory intensive) or can I just `utf8_encode` the whole string. Or should I not be worrying at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-detecting the encoding of a user-submitted file is indeed extremely shaky.

Consider a manual approach:

- Have the user upload the file.
- In an `iframe`, show them a preview of how the data is going to be inserted. (like OpenOffice does when importing an unknown file into a spreadsheet). An illustration of that is [here](http://www.grigsbyconsultingllc.com/images/LinkedInExport/LinkedIn-SpreadsheetImport.jpg)
- Next to that, show a drop-down offering all relevant encodings.
- If the user switches to a different encoding, update the preview on-the-fly using `iconv()`:

  ```
  $data = iconv($chosen_encoding, "utf-8", $data);
  ```
- Once the user has confirmed that the data is displayed correctly in the selected encoding, do a final `iconv()` on the data and insert it into your database.

The downside of this is that the user needs to be educated about an issue that they're most likely ignorant of, and rightly not interested  in. But it's the only way to make sure the data that enters the system is okay.

**Re your comment:**

> I really want to make this transparent to the user. Would doing a utf8_encode on the string at least ensure the proper encoding is set regardless, or would it screw all of the data up?

`utf8_encode` is just a synonym for iconv("iso-8859-1", "utf-8", $data). If the incoming data is not ISO-8859-1, it will get screwed up by the process. It's a tricky issue.

If you need this to be transparent, you'll have to try your luck with `mb_detect_encoding` - on the full file unfortunately, because ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 share the same set of base (ASCII) characters but differ in everything else like Umlauts ÄÖÜ.

Note that encoding detection is close to useless if files come in from all over the world (ie. could have any encoding)

Comment: I really want to make this transparent to the user. Would doing a utf8_encode on the string at least ensure the proper encoding is set regardless, or would it screw all of the data up?

Comment: *I'm putting the contents of this comment into the answer*

Comment: Yes thats what I thought! Damn character encodings!

Comment: Oh, do you know of any server side programs that could maybe detect and encode a file (unix) better than trying to do it in PHP?