# Fix encoding when using file() to get content of text

Tags: php, file, file-upload, encoding

I have upload form catch the `.txt` file and by this code :

```
$file_array = file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
print_r($file_array);
```

I get the content of text , but some some texts get me the content like that `.íÇ ÝÊì¡ Êßæä ãÍÙæÙÇð Åä ÊÎÑøÌÊ`
 Although I opened the text and I found it just fine but another language not english.
So I need `file()` the text with the correct encoding , by the way when I copy this content from text `CTRL+C` and paste it in a text area `CTRL+P` it's appear fine.

Comment: You need UTF-8, all the way.

Comment: it's recommend to use `file_get_contents()` but you will need to encode the string - see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters/2236698#2236698

Comment: @Fred-ii-Yes some files not UTF-8.

Comment: The file itself needs to be saved as UTF-8 and/or adding the UTF-8 in meta tag.

Comment: The users didn't know the UTF-8. :(

Comment: @doublesharp I tried this solutions dosn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8126579/ - or something like and for example `$data = iconv($chosen_encoding, "utf-8", $data);` - `$data` would be the file itself. This taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5713829/

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$chosen_encoding` how to know the file encoding ? it's very hard

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haahaha I used this function on that file , when i set strict `TRUE` it returns nothing and when set it `false` it returns "utf-8" :D what that does mean ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. That is something I've never had to use before. I am very good at researching though ;)